# What's the difference between -r and url@rev in SVN?

Tags: svn, svn-client

Can someone explain the difference between the use of the `-r REV` and `URL@REV` syntax in the following two SVN commands:

- `svn co -r6002 https://svnserv2.acme.com/stx/project1/trunk/gui/Mammoth/WebContent/css`

  svn: Unable to find repository location for 'https ://svnserv2.acme.com/stx/project1/trunk/gui/Mammoth/WebContent/css' in revision 6002
- `svn co https://svnserv2.acme.com/stx/project1/trunk/gui/Mammoth/WebContent/css@6002`

  Checked out revision 6002.

So if I checkout a version of an SVN directory with `-r` it fails, but if I use `url@REV` it works - I would have thought the two were equivalent and unfortunately the SVN docs do not seem to explain the difference.

Answer (score 6):

`-r X` says to Subversion "go to the URL as it is today, and tell me what you know about revision X" (assuming you haven't specified an `@` revision)

`url@X` says to Subversion "go to revision X and find this URL"

The `@` syntax is called a [Peg Revision](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.advanced.pegrevs.html). The `-r X` is the Operative Revision.

It's a very subtle difference, but very important. You'll often use  `-r X` when you're using `@X`.

So if you deleted `https://svnserv2.acme.com/stx/project1/trunk/gui/Mammoth/WebContent/css` in revision 6003, it can't look at that URL now that `HEAD` is revision 6004 (or anything later) because it doesn't exist.

Comment: Thanks, I should have read the manual more carefully (as usual!)

Comment: `-r X says to Subversion "go to the URL as it is today` why is it so?

Comment: @naxa what do you mean? Why did the Subversion developers choose to implement this functionality? Are you questioning the syntax/style? Why it's needed at all? Your question isn't at all clear.

Comment: I cannot see any use when anyone would want to go to head revision and see revision X from there. `Why it's needed at all?` and `Why did the Subversion developers choose to` are my questions. I cannot actually grasp what does it mean to `URL as it is today and tell me what you know about`.

Comment: `URL as it is today and tell me what you know about` - is this about the string value of the `Request-URI` of the HTTP Request? - In any case, `Why it's needed at all?` and the svn dev's design choice are my major questions.