# svn checkout specific revision failed

Tags: svn

I have a directory called bigdeal in revison that I have deleted in revision 4.
Now, I want to check it out that directory but svn fails.

```
[root@localhost ~]# svn ls -r 3  https://******/svn/bigdeal2013/
bigdeal/
branches/
readme.textile
tags/
trunk/
[root@localhost ~]# svn co -r 3  https://***/svn/bigdeal2013/bigdeal/
svn: E160013: '/svn/bigdeal2013/!svn/rvr/4/bigdeal' path not found
[root@localhost ~]#
```

Comment: Your answer is below. I wanted to point out that things may get odd having the big deal directory at the top level with branches, tags and trunk.  Perhaps bigdeal should be it's own project?  The redbook has good documentation: http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.tour.importing.html as well as many questions/answers on this site.  Also, it hurts my soul to see you working as root.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to check out a deleted project from an SVN on the command line](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15875856/how-to-check-out-a-deleted-project-from-an-svn-on-the-command-line)

Answer (score 2):

You want to use the peg revision:
`svn co https://**/svn/bigdeal2013/bigdeal@3`
See Alroc's answer to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15504743/whats-the-difference-between-r-and-urlrev-in-svn)